# ResourceDictionary: System.InvalidCastException

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get an Exception throw and I cant figure out why. My guess is that Im overlooking something simple. The Exception gets thrown in `ResourceSharingPage.xaml.g.cs`

this is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="BookCodedotNet2.ResourceSharingPage">

   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:String x:Key="fontSize">Large</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text=" Carpe diem ">
           <Button.FontSize>
                <StaticResourceExtension Key="fontSize"/>
            </Button.FontSize>
        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If I remove

```
           <Button.FontSize>
                <StaticResourceExtension Key="fontSize"/>
            </Button.FontSize>
```

I can build the app.

Answer (score 1):

In the resources, try something like below. Use double value instead of string as FontSize is a double.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Double x:Key="fontSize">35</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works. I tested it already. But I´ve read that the NamedSize should work, too. Im looking for a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the resource of type `x:String`. `FontSize` doesn't accept values of type `String`. It only accepts values of type `Double` or `NamedSize`. As you mentioned in the comment to Abdul Gani's answer, you should be defining `NamedSize`.

You are better off using the `Style` tag and setting the style of your `Label` that way. Follow **SushiHangover**'s answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49440464/3872145) if you want to use `Style` instead.

Comment: In this book: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2016/03/31/free-ebook-creating-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms/ there is this argument: "A dictionary item for the FontSize property is somewhat problematic. The FontSize property is of type double, so if you´re storing an actual numeric value in the dictionary, that´s no problem. But you can´t store the word "Large" in the dictionary as if it were a double. Only when a "Large" string is set to a FontSize attribute does the XAML parser use the FontSizeConverter. For that reason, you´ll need to store the FontSize item as a string."

Comment: I assumed that it should work the way I do it. I guess it´s just outdated?

Comment: I don't think it should be outdated, but it might be a bug according to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/107102/x-string-in-xaml-resource-dictionary-generates-a-run-time-error).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NamedSize` in resource dictionary in this way:

```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="fontSize" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            </Style>
            <Color x:Key="NormalTextColor">Blue</Color>
            <Style x:Key="MediumBoldText" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text=" Carpe diem "  Style="{StaticResource fontSize}"> </Button>

        <Button Text="Test"
            TextColor="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}"
            Style="{StaticResource MediumBoldText}" />
    </StackLayout>
```